# java.lang.RuntimeException: This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have enable hashtag feature in my app, which I'm not really sure if this is the way how it has to be implemented or not , since I can't test it. it is crashing every time I'm trying to run it.

So I have Image class that has field (tag) of relation type .
HashTags has tagName as string and img as pointer to Image class.

This is the code I've started.

```
 final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Image");
            final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = ParseQuery.getQuery("HashTags");

            final ParseObject tag = ParseObject.create("HashTags");

            query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        public void done(final ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                final String hashTag = add_tag.getText().toString().trim();

                                String text = add_tag.getText().toString().trim();
                                String regexPattern = "(#\\w+)";

                                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
                                Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
                                while (m.find()) {
                                    final String hashtag = m.group(1);


                                    if (hashtag.trim().matches("")) {
                                        object.put("location", point);
                                        object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                                if (e == null) {
                                                    done = true;
                                                    finish();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {

                                        query1.whereEqualTo("name", hashtag);
```

the problem occurs at the last line, when [                                             query1.whereEqualTo("name", hashtag);]

I think because hashtag is not single value, it's more than one hashtag. so it's throwing that error.

any suggestions how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just add a listener to that initial GetQuery and put the rest of the code inside so it can be executed when it completes. That should solve the concurrent queries.

Something like this

```
query.getInBackground(new GetCallbacks(){
    onComplete(){
        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = ParseQuery.getQuery("HashTags");
        query1.getInBackground(new GetCallbacks(){
            onComplete(){
                //The rest of the code.
            }
        });
)
```

I don't have any projects currently to make the code pretty, but this is the gist of it. Sounds like query1 is still executing when you are trying to view its data, You should be chaining together getInBackground anonymous inner classes. By doing this you are ensuring that the rest of the code is executed once query1 completes or fails..

Comment: Thank you so much man for your response, but what is this onComplete method ? do I have to create it ?

Comment: onComplete is not a real method, I dont have the Parse code in any of my projects to get a quick rundown on what the exact names are.. I just know when you pass in an anonymous innerclass it makes you implement an onParseFailure() method & some type of onParseSuccess() method.

I have used Parse before which is why I know some of how this works though.

Comment: So do I have to implement such a method ?

Comment: Give me a few minutes, ill dig up my old project for a complete example.

Comment: Thank you so much , I really appreciate it